# Access deined while configuring mysql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, mysql-8.0

I am following this post on [How to Install MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://www.studytonight.com/linux-guide/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

- Updated package index `sudo apt update`
- Installed MySQL server `sudo apt install mysql-server`
- Configuring MySQL `sudo mysql_secure_installation`, entered password

  - Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
  - Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
  - Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
  - Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
- Connect to MySQL server

  - When I use this `sudo mysql`, I get the following error shown below

    > ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  - When I use this `sudo mysql -u root`, I get the following error shown below

    > ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  - When I use this `mysql`, I get the following error shown below

    > ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  - When I use this `sudo mysql -u root -p`, I get the following error shown below

    > Enter password:

    > ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried resetting the password following official Mysql B.3.3.2 [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) and [How to Change MySQL Root Password in Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxhint.com/change-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/)

- Stopped server `sudo systemctl stop mysql.service`
- Checked the status `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`
- Skipped the grant tables & networking `sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-networking --skip-grant-tables"`
- Started server `sudo systemctl start mysql.service`
- Checked the status `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`
- Sign in to MySQL shell `sudo mysql -u root`, I get the same error

  > ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What is the mistake? How do I correct it?

Comment: Try `mysql -u root`

Answer (score 0):

When you are here: mysql_secure_installation try to insert the password:"rootroot"
In mac is assigned by default.